# How can I delete records in a table so there is one reading a minute?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my mysql database that stores gps readings. It stores readings for different users taken at different times:

[image]

It should contain one reading per minute per user. However, due to a bug in the app that collects the reading, sometimes it has one reading per second per user, which is way too much data for our requirements.

Is there a way I can delete rows from the table using a query such that each user does not have more than one reading per minute? I want to avoid having to write a program to do this if possible!

Thanks!

Comment: I guess, but that's not really going to solve the problem in the long term, is it? Anyway, I can't see more than one reading per minute here.

Comment: The bug in the app has been fixed, so the problem in the long term has been fixed, we have just been left with too much data. The screenshot was to give an idea of the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that deleting a lot of records from a table can be highly non-performant.  Often, it is better to simply recreate the table (or a new table):

```
create table new_gps as
    select gps.*
    from gps join
         (select userid, min(dt) as mindt
          from gps
          group by userid, floor(time_to_sec(dt) / 60)
         ) gpsmin
         on gps.userid = gpsmin.userid and gps.dt = gpsmin.mindt;
```

You can use the same idea for the delete:

```
delete gsp
    from gps left join
         (select userid, min(dt) as mindt
          from gps
          group by userid, floor(time_to_sec(dt) / 60)
         ) gpsmin
         on gps.userid = gpsmin.userid and gps.dt = gpsmin.mindt
    where gspmin is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

a easyer way is to set a **unique key** on the dt column with **IGNORE** Option, so mysql earse all duplicate lines an prevent it for new duplications.

The only thing to do is:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE gsp ADD UNIQUE KEY (dt);
```